# copyFileSync works locally but cant find src on global

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm working on an org package on npm similar to create-react-app in the sense that running `npx create-react-app myProject` will generate all the necessary files.

Here's the code that works *half the time*.

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const CWD = process.cwd();

fs.copyFileSync(`${CWD}/src/myFile.js`, './newDest.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

When I test this function locally it works. e.g. `node src/index.js myProject`

When I test it on a global install e.g. `npx /path/to/project myProject` I get an ENOENT error because it can not find my file being it doesn't exist yet.

Is there a better way to do this with JavaScript or is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the working directory is not setting properly. You should replace `process.cwd()` with `process.chdir(__dirname)`. Try to print and check if **CWD** is correctly showing or not.

Comment: Yes I had to add `process.chdir(__dirname)` to the top of the file and everything works. thanks!